# Connection refused when running mix ecto.setup command, packages installed with asdf

Tags: postgresql, elixir, graphql, asdf-vm

I'm trying to follow the [GraphQL tutorial](https://www.howtographql.com/graphql-elixir/1-getting-started/).

I'm used [asdf](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf) to install the [erlang](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-erlang), [elixir](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-elixir) and [postgres](https://github.com/smashedtoatoms/asdf-postgres). I'm using a macbook.

When I get to the step to run `mix ecto.setup`, I'm getting the following error:

> 20:44:47.318 [error] GenServer #PID<0.1605.0> terminating
>   ** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) tcp connect (localhost:5432): connection refused - :econnrefused
>       (db_connection) lib/db_connection/connection.ex:163: DBConnection.Connection.connect/2
>       (connection) lib/connection.ex:622: Connection.enter_connect/5
>       (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:249: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
>   Last message: nil
>   State: Postgrex.Protocol
>   ** (Mix) The database for Community.Repo couldn't be created: an exception was raised:
>       ** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) tcp connect (localhost:5432): connection refused - :econnrefused
>           (db_connection) lib/db_connection/connection.ex:163: DBConnection.Connection.connect/2
>           (connection) lib/connection.ex:622: Connection.enter_connect/5
>           (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:249: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3

What it could be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to start postgres, according to the [asdf-postgree docs](https://github.com/smashedtoatoms/asdf-postgres) you have to:

```
pg_ctl start
```

And in order to run the commands `mix ecto.create` and `mix ecto.setup` you have to **create a user** postgres with the password postgres, and the postgres user must have permissions to both *LOGIN* and *CREATEDB*, then you can:

Create a default database:

```
createdb default
```

Log to that database, with:

```
psql -d default
```

And create the user with the permissions:

```
# CREATE ROLE postgres LOGIN CREATEDB PASSWORD 'postgres';
```